# how to save the view pager fragment instance in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

when i move to another tab, every time its creating new. 
am getting tabname and catid from server,

```
 private void setTabTitle() {
   Final TabLayout  tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

mviewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
 viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(jSonTab.size());
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mviewPager);

            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    mviewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());      // Get current clicked Tab Position


                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

  return MainFragment.newInstance(CatId.get(position), tabName.get(position));

 }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabName.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return tabName.get(position);
    }
}
```

when i change anything in first tab, and go anyother tab, first tab is refreshing and creating new instance, 
everytime am calling server to fetch the details for the particular tab

Answer (score 0):

Try setting viewPager.setOfscreenPagelimit(noOfPagesInViewPager);

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
      Mainfragment mainfragment;

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
    mainfragment=new Mainfragment();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

     return mainfragment(CatId.get(position), tabName.get(position));
```

}

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabName.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return tabName.get(position);
}
```

}